Hide console logs from some methods
I have jest test
Runs it by command  docker exec -it api5dev-common  npm run test
  it('should handle getProductsList message', async () => {
    const params = {
      rate_id: 643,
      category_id: '0b5d5269-5e79-11e3-bd86-002590552cc0',
      page: 0,
      onpage: 20,
      sort_by: 'relevance',
      sort_order: 'asc',
      filter: {},
      city_id: '90',
      customer_id: null,
      selection_type: 'from_category'
    };

    const response = await lastValueFrom(client.send('api-gateway.common.getProductsList', params));

    console.log(response);
    expect(response).toBeDefined();

    return;
  });
});

When executing const response = await lastValueFrom(client.send('api-gateway.common.getProductsList', params)) ,
I am get a tonnes of console logs.
Can i hide that console logs from all chain of method calls,promises etc which executes during client.send('api-gateway.common.getProductsList', params) ?

This is a bit of a cop-out, but the "real" solution here is to not use console inside that method, but instead use a real logger or something like debug.

A real logger and/or debug would be best. A quick (and possibly stupid) hacky solution would be to override the native method during that call and then restore the default after. This will change for any code run by the code being tested, but unless the test runner executes them in a separate process it will effect that too.

i am new to node js, but excepct there is some methods for working with input output streams.
